# How to change scene with 2-step button method in cocos2d?

Tags: menu, cocos2d-iphone

Two buttons are in the main menu.

First button is for choosing a game,

and second button is to playing that game.

It's simple to just touch+play. But I don't know how to separate these steps.

How can I store this parameter(selected game) and send it to the method(replaceScene)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Learn how to handle global data with singletons! Solved.

Great tutorial by Bob!
http://bobueland.com/cocos2d/2011/how-to-make-scenes/

Answer (score 0):

Use CCMenu to create two buttons. Show different scene on pressing those two buttons.

Answer (score 0):

You probably won't need this but for all else having this same issue, use CCMenu. Here is a link to the CCMenu class documentation.

http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/0.99.3/interface_c_c_menu.html

Their documentation is quite useful. Take some time and read and read through documentation and the other useful instruction they have on their site.